# DB: advantages of relations

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I always think that the relations  between tables are needed to perform cross-table operations, such as join. But I noticed that I can inner join two tables that are not linked at all (hasn't any foreign keys).

**So, my questions:**

1. Are some differences (such as speed) in joining linked and not-linked tables?
2. What are the advantages/disadvantages of using relations bwtween tables?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary advantage is that foreign key constraints ensure the relational integrity of the data.. ie it stops you from deleting something that has a related entry in another table

You only get a performance advantage if you create an index on your FK

Comment: It's not the case that you can *only* get a performance advantage by putting indexes on your foreign keys. Foreign keys are used to optimise queries through query rewrites whether they have indexes or not.

Answer (score 2):

The FK/PK relationship is a logical feature of the data that would exist even if it were not declared in a given database.  You include FKs in a table precisely to establish these logical relationships and to make them visible in a way that makes useful inner joins possible.  Declaring an FK as referencing a given PK has the advantage, as said in other answers, of preventing orphaned references, rows that reference a non existent PK.

Indexes can speed up joins.  In a complicated query, the optimizer may have a lot of strategies to evaluate, and most of these will not use every available index.  Good database systems have good optimizers.  In most database systems, declaring a PK will create an index behind the scenes.  Sometimes, but not always, creating an index on the FK with the same structure as the index n the PK will enable the optimizer to use a strategy called a merge-join.  In certain circumstances a merge-join can be much faster than the alternatives.

When you join tables that are apprently unrelated, there are several cases.

One case is where you end up matching every row from table A with every row from table B.  This is called a cartesian join.  It takes a long time, and nearly always produces unintended results.  One time in ten years I did an intentional cartesian join.

Another case is where both tables contain the same FK, and you match along those two FK.  An example might be matching by ZIPCODE.  Zipcodes are really FKs to some master zipcode table somewhere out there in post office land,  even though most people who use zipcodes never realize that fact.

A third case is where there is a third table,  a junction table, containing FKs that reference each of the two tables in question.  This implements a  many-to-many relationship.  In this case, what you probably want to be doing is a three way join with two inner joins each of which has an FK/PK matchup as the join condition.

Either I'm telling a lot that you already know, or you would benefit by going through a basic tutorial on relational databases.

Answer (score 1):

In relational database terms a *relation* is (more or less) the data structure you have called a *table* - it is not something that exists "between" tables. A important advantage of the relational model is that there are *no* predefined links or other navigational structures that limit the way data can be joined or otherwise combined. You are free to join relations (tables) in a query however you like.

What you are asking about is actually called a *foreign key* constraint. A foreign key is a type of constraint that helps ensure data integrity by preventing inconsistent values being populated in the database.